# Facebook Ads api, I can't manage to create ad(group)

Tags: php, facebook, api, ads, adgroup

With Facebook Ad Api, I can't create ad(group) although I have created the Campaign, AdSet, and AdCreative.
I have followed instruction of facbook guide(with the all required parameters). I can't find the answer by any googling.... What's wrong?
(I just found the change that ADGROUP_STATUS is required now.)

**------------ PHP Codes ------------------**

```
use FacebookAds\Object\AdGroup;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdGroupFields;

$adgroup = new AdGroup(null, $account->id);
$adgroup->setData(array(
  AdGroupFields::CREATIVE => array('creative_id' => $creative->id),
  AdGroupFields::NAME => 'My First AdGroup',
  AdGroupFields::CAMPAIGN_ID => $adset->id,
  AdGroupFields::ADGROUP_STATUS => 'ACTIVE',
));


$adgroup->create();
```

Comment: I am also having this same problem, if I find the solution I will post it.  If you find it, please answer your question and let me know.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use the following curl code, Facebook's error messages on curl are more descriptive.  It's a shame failure messages of this nature don't carry through to the php ads api.  Instead you just get "Invalid Parameter"

```
curl -X POST -F "name=My Ad" -F "campaign_id=<ADSET_ID>" -F "creative={'creative_id': <CREATIVE_ID>}" -F "adgroup_status=<STATUS>" -F "access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>" "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/act_<ad account id>/adgroups
```

You will probably get this message.

```
{"error":{"message":"Invalid parameter","type":"FacebookApiException","code":100,"error_data":{"blame_field_specs":[["account_id"]]},"error_subcode":1359101,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"Add Payment Method","error_user_msg":"You need to have a valid payment method associated with your ad account before you can create ads."}}
```

Which means since you were developing for this and probably using a test app with your user id you didn't realize that Facebook still requires you to have a valid payment method for ads in order to even create a paused ad with a test app.

I would recommend that you start with paused ads as you probably don't want to be billed for it while testing.

I guess the argument could me made (why require live payment credentials in order to create even a paused app}  but also you could argue that the test isn't valid unless all requirements are met.

Hope this helps.  This was my problem